# Escrever ; em .CSV sem separar a célula

Tags: c#, csv

Tenho um projeto em C# que está gerando normalmente um arquivo com extensão .CSV, porem quero escrever um ;(ponto e virgula) mas ele faz é separar a célula. Existe alguma forma de escrever sem que isso aconteça?

Código:

```
arquivo.Detalhe = new List<Detalhe>();
int sequencial = 1;
foreach (var c in clientes)
{
   Detalhe d = new Detalhe();
   var cob = c.Value.First();
   d.Endereco = c.Key.Endereco + "\";\"";

   d.Bairro = c.Key.Bairro.Nome + "\";\"";

   d.Cidade = c.Key.NomeCidade + "\";\"";
   arquivo.DetalheGD7.Add(d);
}
```

Criando o arquivo:

```
var arquivo = Service.CriarArquivo(paraEnviar, inclusaoRadioButton.Checked, motivo);
TextFile.Serializer.Serialize(arquivo, localDoArquivoTextBox.Text + "\\ARQUIVO_.CSV");
```

A foto de como sai o arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ignorem os espaçamentos, são as outras informações que não foram preenchidas ainda.

Creio que não haverá necessidade de mostrar os outros arquivos, já que minha duvida é apenas como escrever o ; sem que a quebra da célula aconteça.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "separar/quebrar a célula"? Onde você está abrindo o arquivo gerado para consultar, no Excel?

Comment: @PedroGaspar o `;` pode ser interpretado como divisor de células em leitores de planilhas como excel e calc. Por favor adicione uma linha de seu arquivo CSV gerado que contenha um `;`, geralmente o que é feito é deixar a célula inteira dentro de `"`. Pode ser que isso seja apenas a configuração de como o seu arquivo é interpretado por esses leitores.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Eu tentei colocar de todas as formas, porem ainda assim não consegui colocar. Tentei configurar o excel para não entender o ; como um divisor de célula mas sem sucesso.

Comment: @BrunoMiqueas coloque o texto do seu CSV, por exemplo, `RUA GOV SAMPAIO; CENTRO - FORTALEZA, FORTALEZA`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Você fala de colocar via código? Tentei via código porem não adiantou. E se eu editar pelo CSV, ele fica de boa. Porem não existe outra solução? E foi isso que quis dizer em "colocar o texto do seu CSV"?

Comment: Você já abriu um arquivo CSV com um editor de texto? Tipo o bloco de notas, notepad++, ...? Se não, faça isso e irá entender

Comment: O ; aparece lá dessa forma: RUA GOV SAMPAIO; CENTRO - FORTALEZA; FORTALEZA;. O que devo fazer?

Comment: só escrever na primeira linha do seu arquivo sep=_

Comment: sendo o "_" o seu novo separador, pode ser qualquer coisa, literalmente, ex: sep=+

Comment: Obrigado a todos, resolveram meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a RFC 4180, item 2.6, um campo que contenha quebras de linha, aspas e o separador de campo DEVE ser impresso com aspas em volta.

Ver: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

---

Detalhe. Você está acrescentando `";"` no endereço, não apenas o `;`, ou seja, seu campo contém o próprio carácter de separação de campos, que pode estar causando o problema, em vez do ponto e vírgula.

Na mesma RFC, item 2.7: Para um campo conter aspas, as aspas devem aparecer dobradas.

```
"Endereço;";"Bairro;";Cidade
"Endereço"";""";"Bairro"";""";Cidade
```

É interpretado como:

```
Endereço; | Bairro; | Cidade
Endereço";" | Bairro";" | Cidade
```

Parece confuso no primeiro momento, mas repare que os `;` ficam com cores diferentes aqui, e que mesmo a quantidade grande de aspas continua deixando os separadores em preto nos lugares certos.